# How To Find Credentials of Host Machine in VM?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, virtual-machine, vmware

I thought I was sshing into an old server, but it turns out to be a VM into which I ssh'd.  I don't know the credentials of the host machine and would like to get this to connect to it directly.  Is there a way I can find this through the VM?

EDIT:
Suppose I just want whatever I can get - in this case, perhaps just the IP, as robmathers notes.

```
dmidecode | egrep -i 'system-product-name'
```

gives me "VMware Virtual Platform".

Comment: If you're looking for user/password info, you're out of luck as Jakuje notes. But if you're looking for just an IP, it could be found, but requires more info depending on what kind of VM it is.

Comment: How would I get the IP? See edit above if possible.  Thanks

Comment: It depends how it's set up. If it's a desktop VM, then the guest's network may be NAT'd from the host, in which case I'd look for the guest's router/gateway IP. Otherwise you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Passwords in Linux are stored in encrypted form and you can't read them. But if you can change the password by mounting the virtual hard drive and modifying `/etc/shadow` (unless the drive is encrypted). There are many guides how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, can you check edit above?  Modifying /etc/shadow seems too excessive, what if I just need the IP?

Comment: `hostname -I` gives you the IP of the host.